# Go back to long Wordpress front page -> "Are you sure you want to send a form again"?

Tags: mysql, forms, wordpress, browser, send

If my Wordpress front page has more than 12 posts, then if I navigate to a single post, and then hit the browser's back key, there's a dialog saying "Are you sure you want to send a form again"? No actual forms are involved (as far as I know), no comments yet. Is this a MySQL issue I'm having? So the threshold appears to be 12 posts (or a certain amount of data). I wish I could have a "longer front page, would suit my site better. I've tried this with a vanilla install (no plugins, default theme, but a fair amount of posts). Is there any way around this? My site is at http://digitalmusik.info/

Answer (score 0):

Been to your site, but I can't repro the issue. Might be a good idea for you to run http traffic monitoring software (like Fiddler) to see what's happening under the covers when you navigate back.

Comment: Thanks, will try that. It happens in Safari on Mac OS 10.6.8, but not in Firefox 5.0.1. You're not seeing it because I just have 12 posts on the front page ;) Do you think that you perhaps could try again, if I increase that number a little?

Comment: A good tip about listening to http traffic, thanks. Fiddler appears to be PC only, I'm trying HTTPScoop at the moment. It seems that this could be related to embedded Vimeo videos. The figure 12 was probably because the first post with an embedded Vimeo video was number 13. When returning to the front page there are 2 POST messages related to one single embedded Vimeo video. They are: "http://player.vimeo.com/log/client" and "http://player.vimeo.com/set_cookie". I could use YouTube versions instead, but they aren't quite as cool... ;)

Comment: Glad my advice helped. If you like, you can upvote my answer. :)

Comment: One could also use an older embedding technology (while still using Vimeo material) but that would cause problems for mobile devices. Any ideas about how to use new embedding mechanisms (to support iPads, iPhones etc) while avoiding unnecessary sending of forms?

Comment: And with regards to voting, I would need a higher "reputation". Best,

Comment: Does anyone know how to use newer video embedding mechanisms (to support iPads, iPhones etc) while avoiding unnecessary sending of forms?

Comment: I suspect that you probably want to ask this question in another forum that is not necessarily Wordpress specific. Try stackoverflow.com

Comment: Sorry... for some reason, I thought this was posted on the wordpress stackexchange site. Maybe you should ask a *new* question on SO about how to embed video that doesn't do posts.